# Topological entropy of $[0,1)\to[0,1), \ x\mapsto mx$ modulo $1$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, modular-arithmetic, dynamical-systems, entropy

Let $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $m\geq2$. How do I calculate the topological entropy of the map $E_{m}\colon[0,1)\to[0,1)$ defined by $$E_{m}(x)=\begin{cases}mx&0\leq x<1/m\\ mx-1&1/m\leq x<2/m\\
\vdots&\vdots\\
mx-(m-1)&(m-1)/m\leq x<1\end{cases},$$
using spanning/separating sets or covering families?

Comment: What's the definition of topological entropy? Isn't there a formula for it?

Comment: [see here](https://www.fisica.net/ebooks/caos/Brin%20ans%20Stuck%20-%20%20Introduction%20to%20Dynamical%20Systems.pdf), it is a rather complicated definition.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a link to a 240-page book.

Comment: Chapter 2.5 and 2.6 (table of contents)